# Defining a grading on the generalized tensor product

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, graded-rings, graded-modules

Let $C$ be a commutative ring, $(E_i)_{1\leq i\leq n}$ a family of graded $C$-modules such that $E_i\cong\bigoplus_{\lambda\in\Delta}M_{i\lambda}$, for each $1\leq i\leq n$. For $\gamma\in\Delta$, define
$$S_\gamma:=\left\{x\in\prod_{i=1}^n\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Delta}M_{i\lambda}\ \big|\ \sum_{i=1}^n\text{deg}(x_i)=\gamma \right\}.$$
Write $(\bigotimes_{i=1}^nE_i)_\gamma:=\text{span}_\mathbb{Z}\{\otimes_{i=1}^nx_i\ |\ x\in S_\gamma\}$. I want to show that $((\bigotimes_{i=1}^nE_i)_\gamma)_{\gamma\in\Delta}$ is a grading of $\bigotimes_{i=1}^nE_i$.

Let $\phi:\bigoplus_{\gamma\in\Delta}(\bigotimes_{i=1}^nE_i)_\gamma\rightarrow\bigotimes_{i=1}^nE_i$ be the canonical mapping. Clearly $\phi$ is surjective. I am not sure how to prove injectivity.

Let $w\in\text{ker}(\phi)$. Then
$$0=\sum_{\gamma\in\Delta}w_\gamma=\sum_{\gamma\in\Delta}\sum_{x\in S_\gamma}\xi^\gamma_x(\otimes_{i=1}^nx_i).$$
Where to go from here?

Comment: Hint: use that $\otimes$ distributes over $\oplus$. Write each $E_i$ as a direct sum of its components and directly compute $\bigotimes_i E_i$ with that.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, thank you for your help. Does this mean that the grading is $(M_{1\lambda}\otimes\ldots\otimes M_{n\lambda})_{\lambda\in\Delta}$? Because we arrive at $\bigotimes_{i=1}^nE_i\cong\bigoplus_{\lambda\in\Delta}(\bigotimes_{i=1}^nM_{i\lambda})$.